# How can I change the secondary monitor wallpaper on my Mac with python?

Tags: python, applescript

I'm trying to get my dual monitors (connected to a MacBook Pro) to display ultrawide desktop backgrounds spanning them both. I've already made a small script that chops the images in half and puts them in corresponding folders (left and right), but every time I wake my computer from sleep it messes with the order and I get two non-matching pictures. I'd like to control this with a python script instead if possible. So far I've got a script that will change the primary display,

```
import random
import os

rand = random.randint(1, 25)
left = r'/Users/nickthomas/Documents/Wide_Background_Pics/Left/' + str(rand) + '.jpg'
right = r'/Users/nickthomas/Documents/Wide_Background_Pics/Right/' + str(rand) + '.jpg'

command = '''osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "''' + left + '"\''
os.system(command)
```

But I'm not sure how I can do the same with the second monitor. Can this be done with AppleScript or some other method?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947716/11722376). You can easily adapt it to your needs, I think, but if you have trouble I can write a full newer here.

Comment: Err... a full *answer*. Autocorrect...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code block inside your script.

```
from appscript import app, mactypes
app('Finder').desktop_picture.set(mactypes.File('/Path/Of/YourPicture.jpg'))
```

Comment: [`appscript`](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/): `pip install appscript`

Comment: Thanks, but this still changes my primary display. Is there a way to modify this for the secondary display?

Comment: You can detect the monitor using then you can change the wallpaper or keep it as it is.
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSScreen/screens

Answer (score 0):

**Works on macOS Big Sur**

For the Default monitor

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set picture of current desktop to "<path-to-img>"'
```

For the second monitor

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set picture of second desktop to "<path-to-img>"'
```